# How to live validate from in yii2?

Tags: php, ajax, yii2

How can I live validate my form without clicking form button?

Model:

```
public function rules() {
    return [
        ['CodeKargah', 'CodeKargah_check'],
        // ...
        // ...
        // ...
    ];
}

public function CodeKargah_check($attribute) {
    $zero = substr($this - > $attribute, 0, 1);
    $len = strlen((string)($this - > $attribute));
    if ($zero == '0' && $len == 10) {
        return null;
    }
    else {
        $this - > addError($attribute, Yii::t('app', 'First number must be zero'));
    }
}
```

After submitting form it works

Comment: Please fix indentation of code before posting it

Answer (score 0):

I solved:

```
public function rules() {
    return [
           ['CodeKargah', 'integer', 'min' => 100000000, 'tooSmall' => Yii::t('app', 'The value entered must be 10 digits.')],
           ['CodeKargah', 'match', 'pattern' => '/^0/'],
        // ...
        // ...
        // ...
    ];
}
```